# Changing image angle in android gallery view

Tags: android, xml

i want my gallery application to be modified , like coverflow. but not exactly like coverflow. the images in the gallery view should be viewed in such a way that it should look like reverse letter "U" . i want to change the angle image in such a way that it has to go slightly  go above the previous image so that i can achieve the reverse "U" for  gallery view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preRotate or postRotate methods in [android.graphics.Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html). Check them once.

Answer (score 0):

There are already widgets out there that you can consider using. I found one http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html that looks very good, but it might not be exactly what you are looking for.

Here is another one based on the interfuser widget. http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/.
They claim to have improved the performance of it.

Whether you can use them as is or not, you can probably use the source as inspiration.